# How to get selected radio button value for multiple instances of radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying get the value of selected radio button using the selector `$("input[name='job-destination[0]']")` and `$("input[name='job-destination[1]']")`. However when I select the radio button in `$("input[name='job-destination[1]']")` it outputs the value from `$("input[name='job-destination[0]']")`

```
<div class="form-group">
    <p>Destination</p>

    <div class="radio-btn-grp">
        <input class="job-destination" name="job-destination[0]" value="Australia" type="radio" required>
        <label for="job-destination">Australia</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio-btn-grp">
        <input class="job-destination" name="job-destination[0]" value="Canada" type="radio">
        <label for="job-destination">Canada</label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
        <p>Destination</p>

        <div class="radio-btn-grp">
            <input class="job-destination" name="job-destination[1]" value="Australia" type="radio" required>
            <label for="job-destination">Australia</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio-btn-grp">
            <input class="job-destination" name="job-destination[1]" value="Canada" type="radio">
            <label for="job-destination">Canada</label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you show the JS code?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your values of `$("input[name='job-destination[0]']")` and `$("input[name='job-destination[1]']")` are equal. For the test purposes try to change the values. BTW, you can get HTML element, value of which you see, just type `console.log($("input[name='job-destination[0]']"))`, for example

Answer (score 0):

When you use `$("input[name='job-destination[0]']").val()` it will always return the value of first element irrespective of whether it is selected or not.

You need to use [`:checked` Selector](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/), along with `.val()` to get its value.

> Matches all elements that are checked or selected.

```
$("input[name='job-destination[0]']:checked").val()
```